# R gen file does not exist

Tags: r.java-file

In my latest example , i am experiencing new kind of troubleshooting :P

Well , with no reason , the R.java file is not generated.

Is there a way to find why and when does this happen ( for future purpose ) ?

Comment: the R.java file is created automatically. But even if its not visible to you then in eclipse go to Project Menu>clean.here you select your project and clean it.

Comment: I know.. thats exactly why i was so confused.. 
Anyway , i just cleaned and rebuilt the project and worked fine :)